# How to use Foundation CSS Calendar Inside ng-include Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, datepicker, zurb-foundation

I need to use Foundation CSS calendar in my AngularJS Application. I included the **foundation-datepicker.min.js** and **foundation-datepicker.min.css** in my project and referenced the same from my index.html.

In my .html page, I used the date picker like `<input type="text" class="span2 dp1" />` and initialised the element in the controller like

```
$('.dp1').fdatepicker({
   initialDate: '02-12-1989',
   format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
   disableDblClickSelection: true
});
```

This initialises the element and works find with default date set.

But when I use the same input element in a view which is included using `ng-include`, it is not getting initialised. It shows an empty input field with no default value set.

How to initialise an element in `ng-include` view from a controller and make it work?

My Application have JQuery libraries included. Is that stopping anywhere. Also I don't want to include Bootstrap in my Application since it is already overloaded.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same behavior, sounds like onLoad is not called with ng-include. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a working solution to overcome this problem, at the bottom of every page included by `ng-include` I put the following:

```
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

It launches foundation internals to load necessary JS code with CSS.